# how to display array values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

sir I'm getting updated values of X,Y,Z from acceleration function and I want to store these values in an array or list.  Is there any way kindly suggest.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    labelX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"X: ", acceleration.x];
    labelY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"Y: ", acceleration.y];
    labelZ.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"Z: ", acceleration.z];
```

Comment: I'd answer the question but I just can't read it.  I suggest reading up on how to use Markdown to format your questions.

Comment: …I'll answer the question when you learn to upvote answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: store one value each in three, corresponding arrays, or create an object to store those three values and create an object at each invocation of your delegate method.

In either case, I'd create an NSMutableArray instance variable to store these in. The second option would be preferable if you're going to be working with these in the future, since you can add more information to the objects, such as timestamps or something.